# Mulesoft Development Environment (Anypoint Studio Version)

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

Mule 4 improvements makes it easier to learn, develop and manage than that of Mule 3. Mulesoft had recently released Mule 4 and for any customer to decide regarding the versions for integration looking forward for the following details:

1. Is Mule 4 stable ?? 
   (Mule 4 is new in the market, since Client has to deal with financial related data and can not effort to take a risk to play with customer data)
2. Since older versions are stable,if customer go with older versions of Anypoint Studio <= 3.9.2, to what extend and till when Mulesoft can provide support to older versions like Mule 3.8.3 as Mule 4 is already in the market??

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, Yes and No.

The runtimes themselves are pretty stable, and once something works you can be pretty sure it stays working.
The problem lies in the development. 
If your use-cases are a bit complex, and you start needing the non-basic connectors you will probably find some bugs. For some you can find workarounds, for some you can't.
In the 6-9 months i've worked with mule 4 however, Mulesoft did show active improvement, and most bugs reported are fixed in a decent timeframe.

One advice i can make though: If you have the choice, run on linux.
Although windows is technicaly supported, we've had quite a few issues regarding windows (Server 2016).
A current one we are facing is that when redeploying an API you have to log into the server, stop the runtime(4.1.5) service, and remove the api files manualy, as the redeploy breaks an API. A patch was provided which reduces the chances of this happening but it's still around.

As for Question two:
The page provided by Alejandro Dobniewski suggests only 7 more months of support for 3.9.
And 3.8.x is already unsupported, extending it to 2021 is possible however. (for a price) (as of 8-3-2019).

For us, this was the motivation to adopt version 4, along with saving us the effort of later switching to 4.
Mule 3.9 applications and code are completely incompatible with mule 4, so every api you develop will have to be re-built from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much for the crystal clear answer -Nicky van Steensel van der Aa! 

We are proceeding with Mule 4.1.5 with all the information I could get so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Mule 4 first GA release was 4.1.1 in March 2018. Current EE release version is 4.1.5. See the release notes for more details https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-esb
2. See support dates for each branch at https://www.mulesoft.com/legal/versioning-back-support-policy#support-matrix. Note that 3.8.x is in Extended Support.

Comment: We are Testing Mule 3.4.2 it seams Stable. Bute we are still missing DataSense Feature in Anypoint Studio 7.3.5. The Studio ist not very stable.

Comment: 7.3.5 is the last and more stable version of Studio 7. It doesn't mean it is perfect, but it resolves a lot of issues present in previous versions. Also note that some problems with datasense come from the connectors. Be sure to use the last version of the connectors. Additionally since my original answer Mule 4.2.1 has been released, which has improved stability and performance compared to 4.1.5.